# How to create installer .pkg file for macOS app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I am working on macOS desktop application and I want to create the installer package file so that it can be installed on any macOS machine, but when I am creating a package file using Packager tool app,
it is installing only my mac machine, not working on another machine, it gets installed on another machine, but when I tried to open it and suddenly it crashed

So can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be a OS version issue. Check for what OS versions the application is built.